# Swap 2 UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to swap 2 table cells. so if the layout is like

123
456
789

and i drag cell 3 to cell 5 it will be

125
436
789

but then if i continue to drag, without lifting to cell 7, then it will be

127
456
389

and animate this all. I have the basic code from [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout/tree/experimental-swap-items) with some edits i made but still has some issues. Like while moving the cell, another cell will look like a copy and follow it as well until i let go, sometimes it will fully duplicate the cell. In my collection view i use one UICollectionViewCell subclass, but i  have 2 looks, a cell with info and a empty cell.

Here is the code

LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout.h - http://pastie.org/7188891
LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout.m - http://pastie.org/7188886

(cannot post code on here because its too long for post)